# How to set Hotadd flag to virtual machines

Tags: c#, vmware, powercli

I am trying to connect to a virtual machine in c# using powerCLI and I need to set the flag on the virtual machine that allows for "hot adding" cpu and memory while the virtual machine is still powered on. Does anyone know the code for accomplishing this?

I am scouring the vSphere documentation for it and I cannot find it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the setting, but the change won't take effect until the guest's next boot. https://communities.vmware.com/message/2166800